# Is it possible to configure a custom label for a monitor device

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a dual monitor setup with 2 identical monitors. Both identify as 'Iiyama North America 27"'. This is a problem when for example sharing a screen in some app because i never know which one is the "left" and which is the "right".

So my question: Can i customize the label for the device? One Screen should identify as "Left" and the other should identify as "Right".

I use Ubuntu 22.04 (gnome) with Wayland.

Comment: I don't know Wayland, but can you do display management by some `xrandr` equivalent, `gnome-randr` maybe? I suppose the outputs are numbered.